# How to use dynamic text with vuetify breadcrumbs

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, breadcrumbs

I'm building a simple product catalog using Vuetify. I'm using Vuetify Breadcrumbs and would like to have the product's name show up in the breadcrumb on the product page.

This code has been edited to show a solution that works. I used a computed property to modify the last breadcrumb to be reactive. Instead of passing "items" in to Breadcrumbs, I'm passing itemData.

Here is Breadcrumb.vue

```
<template>
    <v-breadcrumbs :items="items" class="mt-64 pl-8" divider="/"></v-breadcrumbs>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['items']
    }
</script>
```

Here is Product.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="grey lighten-4">
    <Nav />
    <Breadcrumbs :items="itemsData" />
    <div class="pt-8 pb-12" v-if="productInfo">
      <v-container>
        <v-layout row wrap ma-0>
          <v-flex xs10 offset-1 sm4 offset-sm-0 md6 sm4 md6>
            <v-img :src="productInfo.imageUrl"></v-img>
          </v-flex>
          <v-flex xs12 sm8 md6 class="pa-5">
            <div class="d-flex align-center justify-space-between">
              <div class="title mb-2">{{productInfo.title}}</div>
            </div>
            <div v-html="productInfo.description"></div>
            <v-btn large class="mt-5" outlined color="primary" :to="{ name: 'contact' }">Get More Info</v-btn>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
import Nav from '@/components/Nav.vue'
import Breadcrumbs from '@/components/Breadcrumbs.vue'
import Footer from '@/components/Footer.vue'

export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          text: 'Home',
          disabled: false,
          href: '/',
        },
        {
          text: 'All Products',
          disabled: false,
          href: '/products',
        },
        {
          text: `placeholder`,
          disabled: true,
          href: '#',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  metaInfo() {
    return {
      title: `${this.productInfo.title}`
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.performingRequest = true
    console.log(this.$route.params.id)
    this.$store.dispatch("getProductFromId", this.$route.params.id);
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.performingRequest = false
    }, 1250)
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['productInfo']),
    itemsData () {
      this.items[2].text = this.productInfo.title
      return this.items
    }
  },
  
  components: {
    Nav,
    Footer,
    Breadcrumbs
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    this.productInfo = null
    delete this.productInfo
    this.$store.dispatch("clearProduct")
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found that works was to create a computed property that updates the final breadcrumb to be reactive. The code above had been edited to reflect the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Using an arrow function in data declaration you don't have access to this, so you can't access props.

```
  data(){
        items: [
          {
            text: 'Home',
            disabled: false,
            href: '/',
          },
          {
            text: 'All Products',
            disabled: false,
            href: '/products',
          },
          {
            text: this.product.title,
            disabled: true,
            href: '#',
          },
        ],
      }
```

Like that, it should solve your problem of this not being defined.

Take a [look here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) to learn more about it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Now I'm getting this error "Error in data(): "TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Comment: Are you passing a prop named product? Can you update you code to show your passed props?

Comment: In the component code you added there is not any declaration for product or productInfo not in data() not in props. Actually you don't declare any props in you component, if your are passing them from a parent component you should declare them inside your vue component.

Comment: props items are declared in the child Breadcrumb.vue and passed with :items="items" in Product.vue

Comment: Your component Product.vue is calling some this.productInfo and productInfo is not declared inside it. Product.vue, is parent of the breadcrumb component, so the props should be inside it, and however, always declared, parent or child.

Comment: Thanks for spending so much time on this. productInfo comes from vuex computed: {
    ...mapState(['productInfo']),
  },